# TypeScript - How to infer type information from constructor input parameters?

Tags: typescript

Say I have

```
class Foo {}
class Bar {}

class Query {
  construct(...args: any[]) {
    // snip
  }

  result() {
    // snip
  }
}
```

Is it possible in typescript to say that given:

```
const query = new Query(Foo, Bar);
```

that `query.result()` will have return type `[Foo, Bar]` ?

Comment: `query = Query(Foo, Bar)` -- used this way, `Query` is not a constructor but a regular function. In order to be a constructor it has to be used using `new`. From the OOP point of view, an object is a smart component, not just a dumb container. If the constructor accepts any arguments then your "class" is not a class, it is just a convoluted way to implement a dumb container.

Comment: @axiac typo fixed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use Generics for that:

```
class Foo{}
class Bar{}

class Query<T> {
    constructor(private arg: T) {
    }
    
    query (): T {
        return this.arg;
    }
}

const q = new Query<[Foo, Bar]>([new Foo(), new Bar()]);
const q.query() // typehints [Foo, Bar] as returntype
```

Comment: I hadn't considered trying to lump it into one generic parameter. I think it would have to be Query<T extends []> , ...args: T or similar since I need to know given arg[0] was Foo, response[0] will be instanceof Foo, etc. I will see if I can get some flavor of this to work. Thanks for your input!

Comment: if my answer helped you. I would be happy if you mark it as accepted answere :D

Answer (score 0):

For my specific use case (transforming variables within an Array) I ended up having to use a more sophisticated approach, using the techniques described here: https://medium.com/free-code-camp/typescript-curry-ramda-types-f747e99744ab

```
/* eslint-disable @typescript-eslint/no-explicit-any */
type Length<T extends any[]> = T['length']

type Cast<X, Y> = X extends Y ? X : Y;

type Prepend<E, T extends any[]> =
  ((head: E, ...args: T) => any) extends ((...args: infer U) => any)
    ? U
    : T

type Pos<I extends any[]> =
  Length<I>;

type Next<I extends any[]> =
  Prepend<any, I>;

type Reverse<
  T extends any[],
  R extends any[] = [],
  I extends any[] = []
> = {
  0: Reverse<T, Prepend<T[Pos<I>], R>, Next<I>>
  1: R
}[
  Pos<I> extends Length<T>
    ? 1
    : 0
]

type Concat<T1 extends any[], T2 extends any[]> =
  Reverse<Reverse<T1> extends infer R ? Cast<R, any[]> : never, T2>;

type Append<E, T extends any[]> =
  Concat<T, [E]>;

export type InstanceTypes<
  T extends { new(...args: any): any}[],
  R extends any[] = [],
  I extends any[] = []
> = {
  0: InstanceTypes<
    T,
    Append<InstanceType<T[Pos<I>]>, R> extends infer U
      ? Cast<U, any[]>
      : never,
    Next<I>
  >
  1: R
}[
  Pos<I> extends Length<T>
    ? 1
    : 0
];
```

InstanceTypes correctly converts [typeof A, typeof B, ...] to [A, B, C] as I require.